# Android WebView shouldOverrideUrlLoading, should I call super method or just return false

Tags: javascript, android

My minimum code is below.
Use case is like this:

- If page 1, then get POST data from a method and send it with postUrl.
- If page 2, then send url to ACTION_VIEW activity and let android handle it.
- I'm curious about page 3. In this case I want url to be opened in my Webview.

Inside Page 3 there exists HTML forms. So if I load it with `loadUrl`, POST data is lost. I also can't load it with `postUrl` because POST data is inside HTML page, and I don't want to make a javascript hack to get form's POST data. So I want page 3 to be opened in my WebView. What should I do for it ?

Should I call `super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)` or just `return false` ?

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) is not clear. Calling `return false` without a `super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading`, makes Android to handle url outside of the webview ?

---

```
public class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

  ...

  @Override
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
      if ( url.startsWith("http://example.com/page1") ) {
          String postData = getPOSTdata();
          view.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
          return true;
      }
      if ( url.startsWith("http://example.com/page2") ) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
          startActivity(intent);
          return true;
      }
      if ( url.startsWith("http://example.com/page3") ) {
          //super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
          //return false;
      }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation for `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` returns false. So, as of right now, both are exactly the same. Personally, I think returning false makes the programmer's intent clearer, but it's a matter of style.

Returning false for this method means that the WebView itself will handle the URL. That much is clear in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29):

> If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application
>   handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles
>   the url.